# How to make semi-transparent select2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I make buttons looking semi-transparent with the following CSS applied -

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-image: none;
    border: 0 none;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
       -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .45s;
       -moz-transition: all .45s;
            transition: all .45s;
            float: left;
}
```

But when I apply it to [select2](https://select2.github.io/) component, it doesn't make it looking transparent. Looks like select2 applies its own theme and override what I do. Select2 also [supports themes](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes), but detailed documentations [is missing](https://select2.github.io/options.html#theme).

How should I change select2 styling to look in the same way as buttons (see [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/crxepevy/))

Comment: select2 adds own html so it may the case that you are styling the wrong html. Use the Browsertool to see which elements are generated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crxepevy/2/ Is this what your looking for? You can add containers and all of that but its to hard. just edit the select2 classes. Im just using its structure and applying own rules ontop of that. 
We are all waiting for the THEME# of select2

Comment: @Persijn, yes, this is almost what I need. I also wanted to have dropdown list grey/semi-transparent. Btw, select2 with current style the font is white - i.e. you don't see what you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've try this: http://jsfiddle.net/crxepevy/1/ it's works fine?

**JS**

```
var data = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'enhancement'
}, {
    id: 1,
    text: 'bug'
}, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'duplicate'
}, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'invalid'
}, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'wontfix'
}];


$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data,
    theme: "themes-dark"
});
```

**CSS**

```
<body>
<nav class="mainmenu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-right">
            <select class="js-example-data-array themes-dark"></select>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><font color="white"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg fa-fw"></i></font>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><font color="white"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg fa-fw"></i></font>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><font color="white"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-lg fa-fw"></i></font>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
background:#505D6E url(http://habrastorage.org/files/a01/ca3/b36/a01ca3b360454f539b4275a3ad274c87.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
min-height:100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; }

body {
    background:transparent;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.mainmenu { z-index: 999999; width:100%;  padding: 30px 0 0 0;}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mainmenu { position: fixed; }
}

.navbar-toggle, .themes-dark, .select2-container--themes-dark {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-image: none;
    border: 0 none;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
       -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .45s;
       -moz-transition: all .45s;
            transition: all .45s;
            float: left;
}
select {
    height: 39px !important;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 8px 20px !important;
}

span.select2.select2-container.select2-container--themes-dark.select2-container--below, .select2-container--themes-dark {
margin-right: 20px !important;
margin-top: 8px;
height: 39px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good collapsed. But strange that select2 doesn't work - only one element is shown. Just noticed that there is the same problem with my initial fiddle.

Comment: Add this css:
`.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
span.select2-container.select2-container--themes-dark.select2-container--open {
    height: 220px;
}`
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/crxepevy/5/)

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crxepevy/6/)

Put the select2 in an container.

```
<div class="nav-sel">SELECT2</div>
```

With this you can make it seem like a bootstrap 2 nav element with css:

**css**

```
.nav-sel {
   margin-top: 9px;
   margin-right: 15px;
   float: left;
}
```

Now for the select2: 
Added lots of transparent backgrounds and semi-transparent ones.

**css**

```
.select2-container {
    background: transparent;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection {
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.select2-container .select2-selection span:first-child {
    color: white;
}

.select2-results ul li {
    color: white;
}

.select2-dropdown {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.select2-search input:first-child {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It is great. I've changed color of the selection etc., but can not figure out how to change position of the text - `enhancement` and down-arrow (shown as default element) should be vertically center-aligned.

Comment: I cant seem to get it right in a fiddle, but the arrow can be set correctly by setting: `top: 20px` and `line-height: 40px` should be the fix for that but the fiddle looks diffrent from when i made it.

Comment: Which style should be modified to add these settings?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crxepevy/6/ Here is the new fiddle. Its modiefied to a point that i think its a hack. I have no idea why the arrow is displaying on the left side.